# How to send input from searchview which is in an activity to fragment which is in the view pager of that activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

So i have a searchview placed in an activity which has a tablayout and viewpager.In the viewpager there is a fragment for each tab with a textview.What im trying to do is to get the input from the searchview and set the text of the textview with that input and i cant seem to be able to do it.I tried to put the input from the searchview in a bundle(this being done in the activity),and then get the arguments in the fragment in onCreateView() but the problem is that the activity and the fragment are being created simultaneously wthich means that the input from the searchview would be null.

This is the Activity:

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
SearchView searchView;
Toolbar toolbar;
ImageButton imageButtonBack;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    bindUI();
    
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new NewestFragment(), "Newest"); // this line can cause crashes
    viewPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new OldestFragment(), "Oldest"); // this line can cause crashes
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    setSearchView();
    setImageButtonBack();
}

private void setSearchView() {
    searchView.requestFocus();
    View v = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_plate);
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("searchViewText", searchView.getQuery().toString());
            NewestFragment newestFragment = new NewestFragment();
            OldestFragment oldestFragment = new OldestFragment();
            newestFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            oldestFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            searchView.clearFocus();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("searchViewText", searchView.getQuery().toString());
            NewestFragment newestFragment = new NewestFragment();
            OldestFragment oldestFragment = new OldestFragment();
            newestFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            oldestFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return false;
        }
    });

}

private void bindUI() {
    imageButtonBack = findViewById(R.id.back);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_view_searchactivity);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_selected_category);
}

private void setImageButtonBack() {
    imageButtonBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });

}
}
```

The adapter of the ViewPager:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>(); // this line can cause crashes
private final List<String> titlesList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return titlesList.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titlesList.get(position);
}

public void AddFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    fragmentList.add(fragment); // this line can cause crashes
    titlesList.add(title);
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

And here is the fragment:

```
public class NewestFragment extends Fragment {
View view;
TextView textView;

public NewestFragment(){

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_newest, container, false);
    textView=view.findViewById(R.id.tttttttttttttttttttt);
    try {
        String searchViewText=getArguments().getString("searchViewText");
        textView.setText(searchViewText);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        //something
    }
    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fragments are attached to activity so first activity is created lets leave that but I think you should use a MVVM pattern and create viewmodel and then you can observe the search view and update the fragment textview using that viewmodel class

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-live-data/index.html#0

Answer (score 0):

To change the fragments that are created by a FragmentPagerAdapter, you should use a DynamicFragmentPagerAdapter. Refer to the following code below.

```
public class DynamicFragmentPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "DynamicFragmentPagerAdapter";
  
    private final FragmentManager fragmentManager;
  
    public static abstract class FragmentIdentifier implements Parcelable {
        private final String fragmentTag;
        private final Bundle args;
      
        public FragmentIdentifier(@NonNull String fragmentTag, @Nullable Bundle args) {
            this.fragmentTag = fragmentTag;
            this.args = args;
        }
      
        protected FragmentIdentifier(Parcel in) {
            fragmentTag = in.readString();
            args = in.readBundle(getClass().getClassLoader());
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(fragmentTag);
            dest.writeBundle(args);
        }
      
        protected final Fragment newFragment() {
            Fragment fragment = createFragment();
            Bundle oldArgs = fragment.getArguments();
            Bundle newArgs = new Bundle();
            if(oldArgs != null) {
                newArgs.putAll(oldArgs);
            }
            if(args != null) {
                newArgs.putAll(args);
            }
            fragment.setArguments(newArgs);
            return fragment;
        }

        protected abstract Fragment createFragment();
    }
  
    private ArrayList<FragmentIdentifier> fragmentIdentifiers = new ArrayList<>();

    private FragmentTransaction currentTransaction = null;

    private Fragment currentPrimaryItem = null;

    public DynamicFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }

    private int findIndexIfAdded(FragmentIdentifier fragmentIdentifier) {
        for (int i = 0, size = fragmentIdentifiers.size(); i < size; i++) {
            FragmentIdentifier identifier = fragmentIdentifiers.get(i);
            if (identifier.fragmentTag.equals(fragmentIdentifier.fragmentTag)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void addFragment(FragmentIdentifier fragmentIdentifier) {
        if (findIndexIfAdded(fragmentIdentifier) < 0) {
            fragmentIdentifiers.add(fragmentIdentifier);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void removeFragment(FragmentIdentifier fragmentIdentifier) {
        int index = findIndexIfAdded(fragmentIdentifier);
        if (index >= 0) {
            fragmentIdentifiers.remove(index);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentIdentifiers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(@NonNull ViewGroup container) {
        if (container.getId() == View.NO_ID) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ViewPager with adapter " + this
                    + " requires a view id");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ReferenceEquality")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        if (currentTransaction == null) {
            currentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        }
        final FragmentIdentifier fragmentIdentifier = fragmentIdentifiers.get(position);
        // Do we already have this fragment?
        final String name = fragmentIdentifier.fragmentTag;
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
        if (fragment != null) {
            currentTransaction.attach(fragment);
        } else {
            fragment = fragmentIdentifier.newFragment();
            currentTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment, fragmentIdentifier.fragmentTag);
        }
        if (fragment != currentPrimaryItem) {
            fragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
            fragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        if (currentTransaction == null) {
            currentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        }
        currentTransaction.detach((Fragment) object);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ReferenceEquality")
    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
        if (fragment != currentPrimaryItem) {
            if (currentPrimaryItem != null) {
                currentPrimaryItem.setMenuVisibility(false);
                currentPrimaryItem.setUserVisibleHint(false);
            }
            fragment.setMenuVisibility(true);
            fragment.setUserVisibleHint(true);
            currentPrimaryItem = fragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(@NonNull ViewGroup container) {
        if (currentTransaction != null) {
            currentTransaction.commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
            currentTransaction = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return ((Fragment) object).getView() == view;
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("fragmentIdentifiers", fragmentIdentifiers);
        return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
        Bundle bundle = ((Bundle)state);
        bundle.setClassLoader(loader);
        fragmentIdentifiers = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("fragmentIdentifiers");
    }
}
```